# Animate (jQuery) background color not working on scroll function

Tags: jquery, css

I'm tryng to make a smooth transition on a background color menu with scroll function and animate(). But it's not working, although other properties like changing the width do work...For now I'm using the css method, bu the goal is a "fade in and out" effect...can someone tell me what is wrong? I've searched and others solutions don't work (even with hover functions...) The code:

JS:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (top > 0) {
        //this line works
       $('.menu').css('opacity','0.7').css('background-color','#383737');

       //but not this one:

     $('.menu').animate({"background-color":"#383737"}, 1000);


    } 
})
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ED1847;
    z-index: 1;
    color:black;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Animating colors is not supported in jQuery. You'll need a plugin or jQuery UI to do that.

Comment: But this fiddle works: `http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kw2bB/`

Comment: Of course it does, it has jQuery UI included ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is `css3`. you can use `transition` to make background color smooth via `addClass` and `removeClass` to toggle css class with jquery.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (top > 0) {
$('.menu').addClass('newColor');
   } else {
$('.menu').removeClass('newColor');
   }
 });
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pfknowg/)**

If you want ,you can include `jquery ui` library and make `animate` work.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (top > 0) {
$('.menu').stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#ED1847'
    })
   } else {
$('.menu').stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#383737'
    })
   }
 });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw2bB/196/)**

Answer (score 3):

**Animate Properties and Values**

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example,  width,
>   height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless
>   the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

```
$('.menu').animate({backgroundColor:"#383737"}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @PraveenKumar